# Should I use relationship() in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, memory, sqlalchemy

I'm worry about the performance when using `relationship()` in SqlAlchemy. For example, I have 2 tables: `Users` and `BlogPosts`, and the relationship between them is one-to-many. If I use `relationship()`, `user.blogSpots` will be a list of `BlogPost`, so I suppose a user (Alex) has 1 million `BlogSpot`, oh, `user.blogSpots` is very large because it contains 1 million items, right? If it's right, it must fetch 1 million result rows from database? I think in a real world application, the data are huge and maybe the performance will be slowdown.

So what is the benefit of `relationship()` in SqlAlchemy? Using a normal "sql query" with `limit` clause is better (memory + performance), isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The benefits of the `relationship` are actually pretty straightforward: list/add/remove/update related entities.

The case you describe, however, is one of the special cases where one should work with relationships in a non-default way. I suggest you read [Working with Large Collections](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/collections.html#working-with-large-collections) secion of [Collection Configuration and Techniques](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/collections.html) in the documentation.

Applicable to your case would be usage of `dynamic` relationship, which returns only a pre-configured query, so you can further work on it as you wish:

- apply filters
- apply limits to select only top N ordered by field X, etc

Something like this would be an example of usage:

```
class Users(Base):
    blogSpots = relationship("BlogPosts", lazy="dynamic")
...
user1 = session.query(Users).get(1)
assert user1
top10byDate = users1.blogSpots.order_by(desc(BlogPosts.POSTED_DATE))[:10]
taggedTech = users1.blogSpots.filter(BlogPosts.tags.any(Tag.name == 'tech')[:10]
```